# get a link from the database into the google maps info window

Tags: google-maps, infowindow

i've started very enthousiastic with google maps and managed to get the info from my mysql dbase to the map on my site. The problem i'm facing now is that i want to be able to click through from the info window to a page on my site (the link also comes out of the dbase).

Here is the standard google api code I'm using now ('mijnlink' is the link), i've tried a lot of different things but so far no solution, hope you can help me to find the answer:

```
GDownloadUrl("../phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = GXml.parse(data);
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var mijnlink = markers[i].getAttribute("mijnlink");
        var naam = markers[i].getAttribute("naam");
        var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
        var hotelcampingbungalow = markers[i].getAttribute("hotelcampingbungalow");
        var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        var marker = createMarker(point, mijnlink, naam, address, hotelcampingbungalow);
        map.addOverlay(marker);
    }
});

function createMarker(point, mijnlink, naam, address, hotelcampingbungalow) {
    var marker = new GMarker(point, customIcons[hotelcampingbungalow]);
    var html = "<b>" + mijnlink + hotelcampingbungalow + "&nbsp;" + naam + "</b> <br/>" + address;
    GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
    });
    return marker;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got some other help, the var html in the Createmarker function must be like this:

```
var html = "<b><a href='" + mijnlink + "'>klik hier</a>" + hotelcampingbungalow + "&nbsp;" + naam + "</b> <br/>" + address;
```